# Using jQuery UI autocomplete plugin in Rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

I'm interested in using the [jQuery UI autocomplete plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) in my Rails app. The number of possible values will be small, so I wanted to store them client-side. So I have my controller set up as follows:

```
def index
  @tags = Tag.find(:all).map { |t| t.name }
end
```

And in my view:

```
var tags = <%= @tags %>
```

The problem is that this renders as:

```
var tags = [&quot;tag1&quot;,&quot;tag2&quot;];
```

Instead of:

```
var tags = ["tag1","tag2"]
```

What do I need to do differently in order to stop escaping those quotes inside my tag array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by changing my view code to:

```
<%= array_or_string_for_javascript(@tags) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
var tags = <%=raw @tags %>;
```

EDIT:

in your controller

```
@tags = Tag.find(:all).map(&:name).to_json
```

in your view:

```
var tags = <%= @tags %>;
```

It's the same as what you presented but you're sure it's valid and sure (because escaped) json (+ the query is improved).

I'm still questioning about the XSS + raw...

Answer (score -1):

The thing missing in your controller is **html_safe** - here is an example:

controller

```
@keys = @categories.map { |x| x.name }   
@autocomplete_categories = @keys.to_json.html_safe
```

view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = <%= @autocomplete_categories %>;
    $("#auto").autocomplete( { source: data } );
});
</script>
```

Comment: it's the same effect as using 'raw' but I'm still wondering if it doesn't open to XSS attacks